# Android wear : cannot connect watch over wifi or bluetooth

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to connect android watch with my computer over wifi and bluetooth . I want to nstall the wearable apk on my moto 360 as I am developing watch app. In both cases after the command

```
adb devices
```

it only displays my connected android phone, and no watch.

For wifi

1. I connect my laptop and android watch in same network.
2. Go to settings in watch.
3. Developer options
4. Enable debugging overwifi.
5. Note down the address.
6. adb  connect 192.168.0.*
7. adb shows connected and my port.
8. Then do command adb devices
9. It won't show anything, same with case of bluetooth.

Am I missing out on something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My watch takes some time to ask the option of whether I want to connect the watch from my computer after the above steps, it doesn't happen immediately, and hence I was missing it. Got it running now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're command includes the port:

adb connect 192.168.100.50:**5555**

If the device is not showing do the next steps:

- Disable adb debugging on the watch.
- Enable adb debugigng on the watch.
- run adb kill-server on the computer.
- run adb connect 192.168..:5555.
- run adb devices.

Your watch should appear, also i recommend you to use bluetooth debuggin it's more stable, follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#bt-phone).

Comment: Thanks for the reply , :) I had issues in watch,it doesn't always ask to pair with my comp, got it working.